# почему not found: compass?

Tags: npm, compass, grunt

С помощью Yeoman создал проект. Когда делаю grunt:build то sсss файлы не компилятся. Решил написать отдельную таску которая компилит sass вот код

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        compass:{
            dist:
            {
                options:
                {
                    sassDir:'app/styles',
                    cssDir:'app/styles',
                    environment:'production'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['compass']);
};
```

По нескольку раз пробовал ставить компас и все что с ним связано.

```
sudo npm install -g compass
npm install grunt-contrib-compass
```

В результате пишет

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: not found: compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: А сам Rubyшный Compass у вас есть?

Comment: Нет. После установки все скомпилилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас нету консольной утилиты `compass`, поставляющейся в виде библиотеки-гема для Ruby.

- Поставьте Ruby.
- Сделайте `gem install compass`.
- Убедитесь что процесс завершился успешно.

---

Стоит отметить, что это не единственный способ компилировать SCSS-файлы, т. к. существует также реализация `libsass` на С++ (с версии 3.3 [*догнавшая*](http://sass-compatibility.github.io/) по совместимости Sass 3.4 на Ruby), к которой есть привязки в модуле `node-sass`. Если установка Ruby проблемна, а фишками Compass вы не пользуетесь, можно попробовать другой NodeJS-модуль Sass.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить не глобально и из директории, где сам скрипт.

```
cd /path/to/project/
npm i compass --save-dev
```